# Use textbox for date picker iphone developmnt

Tags: iphone

I am using a UIView to show a form with a text box(text), text box (want to attache this with datepicker) and text box (attach this wit picker to select multiple values)

I want to show date picker on click on text box but when I click on the texbox,it start showing the keyboard at bottom.

Will it be good to use read only textbox for date picker value or should i user table view for my form. Please suggest a link for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean UITextField when you say text box. Check [inputView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) property of UITextField. You can add a custom view instead of the keyboard.